# Shoenfield absoluteness lemma with just $\mathsf{ZF}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Shoenfield's absoluteless lemma asserts that if $\sigma$ is a $\Sigma_2^1$ statement (in arithmetic), then it is absolute to all inner models of $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC}$. I am aware that this result applies to all models of $\mathsf{ZF}$.

However, all proofs that I see uses the absoluteness of well-foundedness, which requires $\mathsf{DC}$. According to [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23920/146831), the trees in the proof can be "canonically well-ordered". I do not see why this is the case - following the proof of Theorem 25.20 in Jech's book, all trees involved are subsets of $\omega^{<\omega}$. Is he saying that the absoluteness of well-foundedness of subtrees of $\omega^{<\omega}$ does not require $\mathsf{DC}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtrees of $\omega^{<\omega}$ are well orderable, so they are well founded if and only if they do not have infinite branches.

Comment: I don't see how that follows without assuming $\mathsf{DC}$. The well-order need not be the order by initial segment. For instance, the tree $T$ may be:
$$
T = \{(0),(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),\dots\}
$$
$T$ is well-orderable by $(0) < (0,0) < (0,1) < (0,2) < \cdots$, but I don't see how it has anything to do with the well-foundedness of ordering by initial segments.

Comment: You don't see how a subset of $\omega^{<\omega}$ can be well-ordered? Simply match each sequence in $\omega^{<\omega}$ with the product of the corresponding primes (adjusting the exponent by +1 may be necessary).

Comment: I see how a subset $\omega^{<\omega}$ can be well-ordered, but I don't see how it has anything to do with the well-foundedness of ordering by initial segments.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I see your point now. You can use the well-order to choose the infinite branch. Thanks!